# How to Map One-To-Many Relation to JSON Model in Slick

Tags: json, scala, playframework, slick

I have 2 classes like this

```
case class Employee(id: Long,
                    name: String,
                    prefix: Option[String],
                    role: String)

case class Report(id: Long,
                  name: String,
                  employee_id: Long)
```

expecting JSON format

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"employee",
   "prefix":"emp",
   "role":"eng",
   "reports":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"report_1"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"report_2"
      }
   ]
}
```

an employee can have many reports (one-to-many) and i have tables connected with foreign key my questions in which way to retrieve data from database i tried inner join like this

```
val query: PostgresProfile.api.type#TableQuery[T]

  def getAllQuery = {
    query.filter(_.isDeleted === false)
  }

================================================

  def getAllEmployee: Future[Seq[Employee]] = {
    val joinQuery = super.getAllQuery.join(reportRepo.getAllQuery).on(_.id === _.employee_id)
    val joinRes: Future[Seq[(Employee, Report)]] = db.run(joinQuery.result)
    joinRes map { tupleList =>
      tupleList.map { tuple =>
        Employee(tuple._1.id, tuple._1.name, tuple._1.prefix, tuple._1.role)
      }
    }
  }
```

i received the data and when i tried to map to JSON it comes with duplicate values too. can anyone suggest way to map or better way to retrieve data from DB with an example.

sorry if i made any mistakes i'm new to playframework and thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

The thing which you are looking is `groupBy`, I guess.

You fetch the data by your join query and groupBy on the employee's ID.

```
val query = employee.filter(_.yourField === yourCondition).join(report).on(_.id === _.employee_id)

val joinRes = db.run(query.to[List].result)

joinRes.map { list =>
  list.groupBy {
    case (emp, report) => emp.id
  }
}
```

or

```
 joinRes.map(_.groupBy(_._1.id))
```

Now

where `employee` is `TableQuery` object of `employee` and `report` is `TableQuery` object of `report`.

Give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

To get desired json you need to map result into appropriate case class.

```
  case class EmployeeWithReports(id: Long,
                                 name: String,
                                 prefix: Option[String],
                                 role: String, 
                                 reports: List[Report])

object EmployeeWithReports {
    implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[EmployeeWithReports]
}
```

Mapping to this case class can be done in `DBIOAction`. Firstly group result by employee id and than map all map entries `(Int, Seq[Employee, Report])` to `EmployeeWithReports`

```
val query = super.getAllQuery
                .join(reportRepo.getAllQuery)
                .on(_.id === _.employee_id)

val action = query.result.map(rows => {
      rows.groupBy(_._1.id).map { mapEntry =>
        val (id, name, prefix, role) = mapEntry._2.head._1
        EmployeeWithReports(id, name, prefix, role, mapEntry._2.flatMap(_._2).toList)
      }.toList
    })
```

Then you can get result calling

```
val employees: Future[List[EmployeeWithReports]] = db.run(action)
```